# Rewrite Rule to remove .php gives back an error when using a trailing slash in the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I've a problem with some rewrite rules for my URL, I'm using this rule to remove .php from the URL of my website

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that when added a trailing slash at the end, the website gives back an error.

Example:

`example.com/test/`  gives back an error

I do think that's because it rewrites it like `example.com/test/.php`, I do not know how to properly solve that

Comment: I assume these directives are in `.htaccess`?

Comment: And would you also care to say _what_ error you receive back?

Comment: @arkascha, as MrWhite said, I get an Interna server error, that's why I added the rule to redirect to the index.php when getting these errors, I know that's useless but I added it only to hide the Internal Server Error page.

Comment: @MrWhite, yes the directives are in .htaccess

Comment: An internal server error" is only the informtion the server hands out to people using the website. Such error does not contain any details, because those are sensitive data. You as the operator need to look into your http server's error log file. That is where the http server logs all details of that specific issue. Typically that is what is required to solve the issue.

Comment: @thenewbie So, how did you get on with my answer?

Comment: @MrWhite I used your rule to avoid the server error, right now I get back the 404 page, thank you, one last thing I'd like to know if is it  possible to make URLs that end .php also with the trailing slash, for example, https://example.com/url.php into https://example.com/url/

Answer (score 1):

> I do think that's because it rewrites it like `example.com/test/.php`

Yes, that is what's happening. But it will do this repeatedly (causing a rewrite-loop) until the server "breaks" with a 500 Internal Server Error.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
> ```

The "problem" with this is that you aren't necessarily testing the existence of the same file in the `RewriteCond` directive that you are rewriting to in the `RewriteRule` directive.

So, this will cause an error (rewrite-loop / 500 Internal Server Error) when appending a slash because `REQUEST_FILENAME` is `/abs/path/to/test` (the resolved filesystem path) and `/abs/path/to/test.php` exists, but it internally rewrites the request to `test/.php` because `$1` is `test/` (captured from the URL-path). It will do this repeatedly until the server *aborts* with an error.

You need to make sure you are always testing the same thing in the *condition* as you are rewriting to later.

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following question on ServerFault with a detailed explanation of this behaviour: https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Additional points...

- You are missing the `L` flag, so processing continues on to the next rule.
- The first *condition* that checks the request does not map to a directory is not required, since you are already checking that `<whatever>.php` exists as a file.
- Minor point, but there is no need to backslash-escape a literal dot in the *TestString* (1st argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) - this is not a regex.

For example, use the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Now, `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php` in the `RewriteCond` directive refers to the same string/file as `$1.php` in the *substitution* string.

So, when you request `/test/`, it will now be testing `/abs/path/to/test/.php` in the `RewriteCond` directive, which doesn't exist, so nothing happens (results in a 404). `/test` and `test/` are, after all, different URLs.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
> RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
> ```

This redirect is in the wrong place. It should be the *first* rule, not the *last*.